# Convert Filtered DataGridView To DataTable in C#

Tags: c#, ado.net

I use `BindingSource.Filter` to filter data shown in a `DataGridView`.  How can I convert filtered data in a `DataGridView` to a `DataTable`??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `BindingSource` actually uses the `DefaultView` of the source `DataTable`. When you set `BindingSource.Filter`, it sets the `RowFilter` property on the table's `DefaultView`, so you just need to call `ToTable` on the `DefaultView`:

```
DataTable filtered = sourceDataTable.DefaultView.ToTable();
```

(I'm assuming the `DataSource` of the `BindingSource` is a `DataTable`; if it's not the case, this solution won't work)

Answer (score 1):

You can always convert datagridview data to datatable by using custom function that iterates thru datagridview row and columns and dynamically generates datatable derived from the structure of an existing datagridview..
Here it is what i have found:.

[How to convert Datagridview Data to Datatable](http://www.sourcehints.com/articles/how-to-convert-datagridview-data-to-datatable.html)